# How to differentiate content tags from formatting tags in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a generic way to differentiate formatting tags like B, BR, P etc. from text containing tags like DIV, SPAN etc. using Javascript. The method should work even if the formatting tags have content in them (for example B or P tags will have content in them.

Comment: Please define the difference between "Formatting tags" and "Containing tags" more clearly.

Comment: `<p>(...)</p>` is a paragraph. It is meant to contain text! (at the block level, when an element like `span` is inline err `%inline`)

Comment: Why wouldn't `<p>` or `<b`> be considered a 'text containing tag'?

Comment: It's far more complicated than your initial question I think. `hr` and `br` don't contain text and are self-closing elements. `img` and `input` are also self-closing elements BUT they do have text in `alt` and `value` (input type text or submit for example) or `alt` (yep, in input type image). And `title` as allowed by WCAG2.0 to improve accessibility in desperate cases. `b` have different semantics in HTML4.01 and HTML5 (former doctype: to be replaced by strong in most but not all cases, latter one: better read WHATWG and W3C specs and then http://html5doctor.com/ ^^)

Comment: This does not sound like a real question; it is based on a false dichotomy, and it is impossible to guess what is really meant (as no purpose is presented).

Answer (score 0):

Selecting elements by tagname can be achieved by using `document.getElementsByTagName` or `document.querySelectorAll`. The latter may suit your needs, e.g.

```
var nontxt = document.querySelectorAll('b, i, em, hr, br');
```

If you need all empty elements in a document, try this (css3) selector

```
var nontxt = document.querySelectorAll(':empty');
```